# debugserver died with an exit status of 0x00000000

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I was running an app on Xcode with the iPhone 6 stimulator using the latest iOS 10. And after some time the app crashed with the following message:

> debugserver died with an exit status of 0x00000000

Here is the screenshot of that crash message:
[image]

I ran the code at 7:56 PM and it crashed 9 minutes later. So does anyone have any idea why this is happening? Is this an indication that the app might crash when it goes to the background or anything else?

Comment: I'm do sometimes get this message as well. Frankly, I don't know it's meaning but I get the feeling that it's related to Xcode sometimes being unable to properly attach the process. All in all, I don't think we have anything to worry about.

Comment: @CanSürmeli Yes you are right. The app I was getting this error for is now live and there is no report of any misbehaving actions.

Comment: Please file a bug at https://bugreport.apple.com. Include `sysdiagnose -q` and `xcrun simctl diagnose`.

Answer (score 0):

To give you further insides of it why it happens there are several reasons:

1. The `debugserver` crashed or was terminated by another process
2. More likely the `debugserver` had a memory or CPU usage peak which invoked termination.

To fix this, update your version and see for updates or wait for next patches, releases from apple.

Also check for specific processes that use up a lot memory or CPU usage below (e.g. Chrome / Firefox) terminate them and observe it happen more frequent or not at all anymore.

I think that's all what you can do on YOUR side. I hope that brings a bit more clarity where the problem lies.